# How to add a border to a form?

Tags: html, css

How can i add a border to a form i tried `<border:2px;>` but that does not work, I also tried adding a background image to the form but with no success i tried

```
.form-all {
background: url(url.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

Here is my form

```css
form {
  border: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="EmailForm" action="" method="post">
  <label> Number hours: </label>
  <Select class="form-control input-sm error" min="3" name="Hours" id="Hours" onChange="calculatePrice()" placeholder="<?php echo $RoomErr;?>">
<OPTION value="0">Select Number of Hours</OPTION>
<OPTION value="45">3 Hours</OPTION>
<OPTION value="60">4 Hours</OPTION>
<OPTION value="75">5 hours</OPTION>
<OPTION value="90">5 hours +</OPTION>
</select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Would You Like Ironing? </label>
  <Select NAME="ironing" id="ironing" onChange="calculatePrice()" class="form-control input-sm error" placeholder="<?php echo $ironingErr;?>">
<OPTION value="0">Would you Like Ironing?</OPTION>
<OPTION value="8">Yes</OPTION>
 <OPTION value="0">No</OPTION>
 </select>
  <br><br> Your Estimated Quate: £<input class="transparent-input" type="text" id="PicExtPrice">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
border:2px solid #000;
```

Or, you can replace #000 with any colour you like.

Comment: background: #000; or any colour you like